# is it possible to get cocopods session in GitHub CI workflow automatic

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am work in GitHub Actions to push a component to cocoapods, but the cocoapods need to get a session before push a lib. The process about the interaction was that the cocoapods send a email and click the link in the email. But the problem is I am in a automatic workflow. I can not  click the email every time when publish the component. I want to get the session siliently and automaticlly. is it possible? Or I have to click the link in the email send by cocopods? This is the workflow script:

```
name: validate
on: [push]
jobs:
  unit-tests:
    runs-on: macos-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        destination:
          [
            'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 12 Pro',
          ]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Run Tests
        run: |-
          cd Example
          xcodebuild test -scheme SwiftAudio-Example -destination "${destination}" -enableCodeCoverage YES
        env:
          destination: ${{ matrix.destination }}
          
      - name: Get Sesssion
        run: pod trunk register ${{ secrets.COCOPOD_GMAIL }} ${{ secrets.COCOPOD_USERNAME }} --verbose
      - name: Push Repo to Cocoapods
        run: pod trunk push SwiftAudioEx.podspec --allow-warnings
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use CocoaPods access token:
https://fuller.li/posts/automated-cocoapods-releases-with-ci/